# Component groups of commutative group schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, abelian-varieties

I'm interested in the following question.

Suppose $P$ is a smooth commutative group scheme over a global field $k$, such that $P$ is separated and *locally* of finite type.

Suppose, in addition, $P^0$ is of finite type and projective (hence an abelian variety), and that $P$ has a countable stratification by disjoint finite type open subschemes, each the increasing union of open quasi-projective subschemes.

> Is the component group $P/P^0$ a finitely generated abelian group?

**Example.** If $X/k$ is a smooth projective variety, and $P = \text{Pic}_{X/k}$, this is the well known Theorem of the Base of Lang and Néron. That proof reduces the statement to the fact that $P(k)$ modulo the image of a Chow trace is finitely generated (a generalization of the Mordell-Weil theorem), but such reduction is performed using the fact that for a sufficiently generic $k$-curve $C$, the subgroup $G_0$ of the group $G$ of divisors on $X$ generated by those divisors such that $\text{deg}(D\cdot C)=0$, has $G/G_0\simeq\mathbf{Z}$. An analysis of $G_0$ then allows the reduction.

I haven't given any thought about this yet, but could it be that one can run some argument for $P$?

Comment: Any connected group scheme locally of finite type over a field is automatically of finite type (even quasi-projective), so $P^0$ is always of finite type. The stratification hypothesis is irrelevant, since the trivial 2-step stratification can be used.  The answer to the question is no: use the product of an abelian variety and the constant group associated to any abelian group (e.g., one that isn't finitely generated).  The Theorem of the Base, concerning the geometric component group, is a remarkable and deep result which moreover holds over any field at all (it has no arithmetic content).

Comment: @nfdc23 Where is a modern proof of the Thm of the base? I only read the original, and translated it using Chow traces. I don't know a true reference though, where I can double check my work.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103636/modern-proof-of-the-theorem-of-the-base

Comment: You're a brave person; I never tried to read the original (only read the one in SGA6 indicated at the link given by @JasonStarr, since it gives a fantastic relative result across the geometric fibers in a family).

Comment: You can even take $P$ to be a countable discrete abelian group that is not finitely generated (e.g. $\mathbb Q$, viewed as disjoint union of copies of $\operatorname{Spec} k$). Then $P^0$ is a point. This is the easiest instance of @nfdc23's example.